# Selenium Automate Clicking "We value yout privacy" Pop-Up

Tags: python, selenium, popup

I am using Selenium with Python on a webpage with JavaScript. The script runs until a pop=up asks for a click either to agree or seek More Options labels appear. The HTML for the pop-up disappears if an option is manually clicked. Would appreciate some guidance on how to click "Agree" automatically.

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/A38/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.maximize_window()
    # Navigate to the application home page
    driver.get("https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results/2020-11-23")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the button with text AGREE. First induce waits for page load and then wait for the element to be clickable.

```
driver.get('https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results/2020-11-23')
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='AGREE']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qc-cmp2-ui"]/div[2]/div/button[2]').click()
```